# How to read CSV files with GNU Octave if the delimiter is ;?

Tags: excel, csv, octave

I have an `.csv` file made in Excel and that Excel uses `;` as delimiter. I don't like that, but I cannot change it.

So I have to accept it.
I want to read that `.csv` file in `GNU Octave`, but I can't really do it because the float numbers inside the `.csv` file is separated with `,` e.g `15,25` and not separated with `.` e.g `15.25` because in Excel, it assumes that `15.25` is a text string and `15,25` is a number. Yes, I know, it's weird.

If I change all `,` to `.` in my `.csv` file, then I can read the `.csv` file with `dlmread` or `csvread`. But in this case, I don't want to change `,` to `.` because that's a standard Excel configuration.

So my question is:

If you have a `.csv` file were the float numbers are displayed with `,`. How can you read that `.csv` file in `GNU Octave` then?

Comment: Can we have a demo file, please?

Comment: The MATLAB solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8204080/7328782) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36103686/7328782) might be useful as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a much more flexible csv reader than the default matlab-compatible `csvread` and `dlmread`, use the `csv2cell` function from the `io` pkg. If you haven't used packages before, this is how you would do that:

```
pkg install io -forge   % install io package if you haven't already
pkg load io             % load it
```

Then use csv2cell to read the values as strings into a cell (declaring `;` as the desired delimiter); then use `strrep` to replace `,` to `.` in your strings; and then finally use `str2double` to convert those strings to numbers.

You can do this with the following one-liner:

```
str2double( strrep( csv2cell( 'testo.csv', ';' ), ',', '.' ) )
```

You could also wrap this into an anonymous function:

```
read_my_csv = @( myfile ) str2double( strrep( csv2cell( myfile, ';' ), ',', '.' ) );
Data = read_my_csv( 'data.csv' );
```

---

PS. Tux the penguin added for extra perfection, as requested.

```
         _nnnn_                      
        dGGGGMMb     ,"""""""""""""".
       @p~qp~~qMb    | Linux Rules! |
       M|@||@) M|   _;..............'
       @,----.JM| -'
      JS^\__/  qKL
     dZP        qKRb
    dZP          qKKb
   fZP            SMMb
   HZM            MMMM
   FqM            MMMM
 __| ".        |\dS"qML
 |    `.       | `' \Zq
_)      \.___.,|     .'
\____   )MMMMMM|   .'
     `-'       `--'
```

<sub>(source: https://www.asciiart.eu/computers/linux)</sub>

Comment: I like that. Can you make this answer more perfect?

Comment: Done. I added a linux penguin. Can't get more perfect than that!

Answer (score 2):

### Sample file

```
i1;i2;i3
1,234;34,134;5,987
3,14;6,96;85,05
```

### Script

```matlab
nrows = 2;
ncolumns = 3;

data = textscan (fopen("data.csv", 'r'), "%s", "Delimiter", ";", "HeaderLines", 1);
data = cell2mat(data);
data = str2double(strrep(data,',','.'));
data = reshape(data, ncolumns, nrows); % elements are accessed in column-major order
data = transpose(data)
```

### Logic

1. We read the contents of the file as strings separated by `;`.
2. We replace the `,` present in the strings with `.`.
3. Convert the strings to doubles.
4. The data is reshaped to a matrix.

### References

- [Specify decimal separator for .dat file in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555743/specify-decimal-separator-for-dat-file-in-matlab/8659747#20556378)

Comment: Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: I turned the file into a function and created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/kitswas/34befa9d22c08a2ee79e2614eac92e3c).

Comment: Just download the script into your working directory and call the function. `read_improper_csv("data.csv", 2, 3, ";", 1)`

Comment: Click on [`Raw`](https://gist.github.com/kitswas/34befa9d22c08a2ee79e2614eac92e3c#file-read_improper_csv-m) and save the file.